# Converting MySQL string date to Y-m-d H:i:s

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to convert a MySQL string date into `Y-m-d H:i:s` format.  I am using this SQL at the moment, but it returns a null value.  What am I doing wrong?

```
select 
date_format(str_to_date(week_ending,'%l %d %F %Y'),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') as week_ending 
from worksheets
```

**Edit**

week_ending is in this format: `Friday 08 May 2015`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How your `week_ending` are stored in DB ?

Comment: `Friday 08 May 2015`

Comment: What's the datatype of `week_ending`? Timestamp or String?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct format for `str_to_date` should be

```
mysql> select str_to_date('Friday 08 May 2015','%W %d %M %Y');
+-------------------------------------------------+
| str_to_date('Friday 08 May 2015','%W %d %M %Y') |
+-------------------------------------------------+
| 2015-05-08                                      |
+-------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The format that you are using will return null

```
mysql> select str_to_date('Friday 08 May 2015','%l %d %F %Y');
+-------------------------------------------------+
| str_to_date('Friday 08 May 2015','%l %d %F %Y') |
+-------------------------------------------------+
| NULL                                            |
+-------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Here is the list of formatting Specifier https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format